# Why hidden layers of neural networks often contain 64, 128, 256 neurons?

Tags: neural-network

When looking for classic neural nets architectures on the web, I find that very often, hidden layers of neural networks contain 32, 64, 128, 256... neurons.

Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the number of hidden neurons is either picked through experimentation or as part of a model selection algorithm doing some sort of grid search. The numbers you give are all powers of two, and I have never seen any research to indicate that a power of two is more effective than another number as a hidden neuron count.  I think it is just a matter of a programmer picking conveniently aligned memory block, which MIGHT give some small processing power boost if you hit the page boundary just right.

How often have you seen C/Java/C# code with something like this.

char buffer[1024];

Answer (score 0):

Apart from memory alignment, there is one more hardware based reasoning for this choice. Matrix multiplication is at the [heart](https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/) of deep learning computations. Modern CPUs support SIMD operations via extensions like AVX, which process numbers in batch sizes, which are powers of 2.